# Why is my background-image not visible with a radial gradient applied?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I want to add radial gradient to a photo, starting from the top right part of the image. I have tried a lot of combinations, here is what I managed to do:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at top right, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%), url("../images/banner-image.png");
```

My problem is: it doesn't show my photo. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Uivari, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please update your post to include a [mcve]? You can try to use a sample image that is hosted online or upload your real one somewhere (including here). Also keep in mind that if an absolute URL works but your relative one does not, then it could be an issue with either your relative URL path in the code or with where you have placed the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using solid colors rather than colors with transparency in order to see the image below.

Use `rgba` colors instead

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), blue), url(http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Is there some way that I can change the circle's radius? I want my photo to be light only in the right top part.